# How do I handle unhandled Application level exceptions in a WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I'm migrating an existing Winforms based application to WPF.

For handling unhandled exceptions at the application level in my Winforms app, I did the following:

```
Application.ThreadException
    += new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);     

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException
    += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);   

Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);
```

How do I go about handling these conditions in a WPF based application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can handle the event `DispatcherUnhandledException` of the current instance of Application:

```
Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException += (s,e) => {...};
```